# configmaps is forbidden error when attempting helm ls

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
Error: configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:k8s-tiller:k8s-tiller" cannot list configmaps in the namespace "k8s-tiller": clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "tiller" not found
```

Can someone explain this error? The `"k8s-tiller": clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "tiller" not found` does not make sense to me. What is this meant to indicate?

Please ignore how to actually solve the error, I'm just looking for an explanation of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error for **RBAC**( to know more about RBAC, see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)).

**Serviceaccount** `k8s-tiller` in namespace `k8s-tiller` has no permission to list `configmaps` in namespace `k8s-tiller`. Also **Clusterrole** `tiller` does not exist in your cluster. The ClusterRoleBinding or RoleBinding you created for your serviceaccount `k8s-tiller` included ClusterRole `tiller` as `roleRef`. But that ClusterRole `tiller` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm what nightfury is saying but you don't need to set a K8S Clusterrole, you just need to deploy a tiller for your namespace and give it the right Role/Rolebinding and Service Account

For deployment and History usage, you might prefer to deploy a tiller per K8S namespace
to not override for example some deployments with the same name

So to do this:

Create an SA:

```
kubectl create sa tiller-deploy-sa
```

Create Role:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: <Your_namespace>
  name: tiller-deploy-role
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

Please note that this role is not recommanded for PROD and used for example purposes only

```
kubectl apply -f <filename>.yml
```

Create Rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller-deploy-rolebinding
  namespace: <Your_namespace>
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: tiller-deploy-role
  namespace: <Your_namespace>
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller-deploy-sa
  namespace: <Your_namespace>
```

Apply the file created

```
kubectl apply -f <filename>.yml
```

You can read more using K8S documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/